# Error when unpacking snapshot to bootstrap Cardano node by using Mithril

Tags: cardano-node, error

I'm trying to bootstrap a Cardano node on `preview` network by using Mithril follow this instruction:

https://mithril.network/doc/manual/getting-started/bootstrap-cardano-node/

In step "Restore Selected Snapshot", I had a problem after downloading `c9839be0355587c4a9a3bcff4a5285001b12e2f2b7ea3ac38bb2dc1ab25d3baf` snapshot.
[image]

Then I used all snapshots are listed but it still had encountered the above error.

Please let me know how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using a wrong aggregator endpoint. In order to make the restoration work, please use the following endpoints:

- Cardano `preprod` network: https://aggregator.release-preprod.api.mithril.network/aggregator
- Cardano `preview` network: https://aggregator.pre-release-preview.api.mithril.network/aggregator

The Mithril networks configurations are also available in our documentation website at https://mithril.network/doc/manual/developer-docs/references#mithril-networks